# How to insert media query in vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

How to run this javascript on SP view only.

```
const navTrigger = document.querySelector('.nav__trigger');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

navTrigger.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    navTrigger.classList.toggle('nav__trigger--active');
    nav.classList.toggle('nav--open');
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)')
    document.body.classList.toggle('overflow'); // THIS CODE
});
```

Comment: Your code isn't making much sense. please explain what exactly you want.

Comment: Hi, are you wanting to toggle overflow only if the media has a min width of 768px (at the moment you don't seem to be doing anything with mediaQuery) and if so are you sure you want to toggle overflow or do you want to definitely set it?

Comment: @Mr_Green  document.body.classList.toggle('overflow'); this code should work in mobile view only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `matchMedia()` Find out if the screen is less than or greater than 768 pixels wide. And if the condition is met executes the code

```
const navTrigger = document.querySelector('.nav__trigger');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

navTrigger.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    navTrigger.classList.toggle('nav__trigger--active');
    nav.classList.toggle('nav--open');

    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
        document.body.classList.toggle('overflow'); // THIS CODE
    }
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you.  document.body.classList.toggle('overflow'); this code should work in mobile view only.

Answer (score 1):

#### Listen for changes

```
// Create a condition that targets viewports at least 768px wide
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)')

function handleTabletChange(e) {
  // Check if the media query is true
  if (e.matches) {
    // Then log the following message to the console
    console.log('Media Query Matched!')
  }
}

// Register event listener
mediaQuery.addListener(handleTabletChange)

// Initial check
handleTabletChange(mediaQuery)
```

#### more example

```
// media query event handler
if(matchMedia) {
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
        // window width is at least 500px
    } else {
        // window width is less than 500px
    }
}
```